# How to return a 2d vector in C++ which all of its elements are 1

Tags: c++, vector, initialization

I am new to C++ and I want to create a 2d vector which all of its elements are 1. When I run my code the compiler returns nothing!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

vector<vector<double>> ones2d(int m, int n) {
    vector<vector<double>> vect;
    for (int i = 0; i < m; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++){
            vect[i][j] = 1;
        }
    }
    return vect;
}

int main(){
    vector<vector<double>> vect = ones2d(2,3);
    cout << vect[0][0] << endl;
}enter code here
```

Comment: Entries are not added to a vector by using `[ ]`.

Comment: If you later want to add entries to an already created vector, `resize()`, `push_back()`, `insert()`, and iterators that use those functions such as `std::back_inserter` are used to add entries.  The `[ ]` is only used to *access* already entries in a vector, not create them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `resize()` function is used to resize a vector to the specified size. We can use it to initialize a `2d` vector with given default value :

```
std::vector<std::vector<double>> ones2d(int m, int n)
{
    const int default_value = 1;

    std::vector<std::vector<double>> vect(m);
    for (int i = 0; i < m; i++)
        vect[i].resize(n, default_value);

    return vect;
}
```

Or you can use of fill constructor to initialize a `2d` vector :

```
std::vector<std::vector<double>> ones2d_2(int m, int n)
{
    const int default_value = 1;

    return std::vector<std::vector<double>>(m, std::vector<double>(n, default_value));
}
```

I recommend use of the second solution.

Please try it [**online**](http://cpp.sh/3jbowd)

Comment: This is inefficient.  You can construct the entire vector at once.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie fixed

Comment: You don't even need to create a temporary `vect`.  Just `return std::vector<...`

Comment: `return std::vector<std::vector<double>> (m, std::vector<double(n, default_value));`  Why waste time creating a temporary?  It would be similar to `int x = 10; return x;` instead of just `return 10;`

Answer (score 2):

`vector<vector<double>> vect;` initializes an empty vector of vectors (size is 0), so any access to it's elements is out of bounds, which causes undefined behaviour.

One way to get a 2D-vector with some default value would be:

```
vector<vector<double>> ones2d(int m, int n) {
    // Create vector of n doubles, all initialized to 1
    vector<double> dim1(n, 1); 

    // Create vector of vectors, containing m copies of dim1
    vector<vector<double>> res(dim, m); 

    return res;
}
```

---

Of course you can combine this into a one-liner, but it's easier to understand if broken down.